# Why in primary constructors are non val or var parameters usable in the code?

Tags: scala, constructor

I have this code.

```
class VBO (size: Int, usage: Int,
    private val vao: Int = GL30.glGenVertexArray(), 
    private val vbo: Int = GL15.glGenBuffers())
```

Why can I use size and usage in other methods in the class? Also what are they considered (fields, methods, ect.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are usable because, presumably, you need them for some reason, seeing as you declared them as parameters. They are effectively `private val` if you use them on `def` or `lazy val`. If you do not use them at all, or only to initialize `val` or `var`, they exist only in the constructor, and are not part of the instances created.